# Asterisk make crashes with cannot find -lwebrtc-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Tags: linux, asterisk

I do `./configure with-pjproject-bundled`, and it runs OK. Then, I issue `make`, and it crashes with `cannot find -lwebrtc-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`. Full stack here:

```
CC="cc" CXX="g++" LD="" AR="" RANLIB="" CFLAGS="" LDFLAGS="" make -C             
menuselect CONFIGURE_SILENT="--silent" makeopts
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/asterisk-14.4.0/menuselect'
make[1]: `makeopts' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/asterisk-14.4.0/menuselect'
Generating input for menuselect ...
menuselect/menuselect --check-deps menuselect.makeopts
menuselect/menuselect --check-deps menuselect.makeopts
Generating embedded module rules ...
[LD] libasteriskpj.o -> libasteriskpj.so.2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwebrtc-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libasteriskpj.so.2] Error 1
make: *** [main] Error 2
```

I use RedHat 7.3 and Asterisk 14.4.
If I do `./configure` without parameters, then `make` runs without an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have the webrtc library installed. Try `yum install webrtc-audio-processing-devel` and see if that works

Comment: @miken32 thanks for answer, but no luck, still same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you clean your config after installing the library?

Comment: @miken32 firstly no, then I did `./configure --with-pjproject-bundled` again, then `make clean` and `make` and this seems to solve this problem. Now I have `/usr/bin/ld: chan_sip.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol \`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.38245' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`, but it appears to be different problem, so I'll wrap it in another Question

Comment: You want to `make clean` and then re-run `configure`. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re simply missing a library. Run this command to install it:

```
yum install webrtc-audio-processing-devel
```

Then clear out your settings before running `configure` again:

```
make clean all
```

---

I’m not at my computer now but I believe there’s a script bundled with the code that installs all the dependencies for you. Might be worth checking out.

Comment: Exactly. Installing lib, `make clean`, `make dist-clean` and then repeating the configure-make process helped me.